# How can i fit 4 boxes vertically in a div with diffrent height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a Main div position absolute, top:0, bottom:0 width:500px; and 4 divs in it . See attached image. I want the Main div's inside boxes responsive if i adjust window height. 1,2, and 3 has fixed height 100px and 4th box is responsive.

[image]

Comment: show the code you tried doing it

Comment: Give you containers height based on `vh` unit (viewport height). Or if that's not what you want, base it on % of the surrounding box.

Comment: @connexo vh is already % , 40vh is 40% of viewport height :-)

Comment: @ddlab Not necessarily. If the surrounding box is inside a container that is higher or less high than 100vh it's not.

Comment: What's the reason you use `position: absolute`? ... I mean that does not normally count as being responsive

Comment: Guys as we use table tr td which can b responsive for horizontal stetch.. So how to make this possible in a vertical table

Comment: The solution to this depends somewhat on how the markup looks like, so please update your question with the existing markup/CSS

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks to nashcheez to create codes)I suggest to using flex:

```css
.parent {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;  
  height: 100px;
}

.last{    
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div style="background-color: yellow;" class="child">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue;" class="child">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: purple;" class="child">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: green;" class="last">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to make all 3's fix height and 4th one responsive 
So.
.child {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
Thanks alot...

Comment: You welcome. I had a misunderstand about height and i fixed that. If my answer is true please check that as write answer so other people could use this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your height in percentage for the desired effect.

Refer to the following fiddle and check on resize: https://jsfiddle.net/cn5bd6qq/

Attached code:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="background-color: yellow;" class="child">

  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;" class="child">

  </div>
  <div style="background-color: purple;" class="child">

  </div>
  <div style="background-color: green;" class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

User percentage for height to the 4th div.